# python - tsne reduce memory consumption

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf, sklearn-pandas

I have a very large csv file that I am trying to do a tf-idf analysis with. I am using the tfidvectorizer for sklearn and then I want to reduce the dimensionality using tsne so I can plot the results. However, whenever I use tsne, I get a memory error. Is there a way I can prevent this from happening? I read you can use svdTruncate before implementing tsne. How would I go about doing this (or are there any other suggestions)? Here is my code:

```
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.95, min_df=2,max_features=n_features,stop_words='english', lowercase = False)

tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(df['paper_text'])
nmf = NMF(n_components=n_topics, random_state=0,alpha=.1, l1_ratio=.5).fit(tfidf)
nmf_embedding = nmf.transform(tfidf)
nmf_embedding = (nmf_embedding - nmf_embedding.mean(axis=0))/nmf_embedding.std(axis=0)
tsne = TSNE(random_state=3211)
tsne_embedding = tsne.fit_transform(nmf_embedding)
tsne_embedding = pd.DataFrame(tsne_embedding,columns=['x','y'])
tsne_embedding['hue'] = nmf_embedding.argmax(axis=1)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your number of features is big you can apply PCA(~25) before TSNE.